# Is $X\times_ST$ a Noetherian scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, noetherian

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme. Given two morphisms of schemes $\pi:T\to S$ and $f:X\to S$, if $\pi$ is flat, is $X\times_ST$ a Noetherian scheme?

Comment: I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154263/is-a-product-of-two-noetherian-schemes-over-spec-mathbb-z-a-noetherian-scheme should answer your question. In particular, there are examples where $S = \mathrm{Spec}(k)$, and $T = X = \mathrm{Spec}(K)$ for some field extension $K/k$. In this case, both $T$ and $X$ are Noetherian, and $\pi$ is (faithfully!) flat, so it's not even true with stronger assumptions, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. But I assume the you asked this question for the problem in this picture [image]
i.e. Exercise 5.1.16 in Qingliu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curve.
For this exercise, the key step is to show that $f_{T,*}$ preserves quasi-coherent sheaves when $X$ is Noetherian. Here is the idea:

1. Since being quasi-coherent is a local property, we may assume that $T$ is affine.
2. By shrinking $T$, we may further assume $\pi(T)\subset U$ for some open affine $U\subset S$.
3. We have $X_T=(X_U)_T$. And $X_U=f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subscheme of the Noetherian scheme $X$, so $X_U$ is also Noetherian. We may suppose that $S=U$ is affine.
4. Since $X$ is Noetherian, $X$ can be covered by a finite open affine covering s.t. each intersection is covered by a finite open affine covering.
5. So $X_T$ can also be covered by a finite open affine covering s.t. each intersection is covered by a finite open affine covering (since $S$ and $T$ are affine now).
6. And this is the ultimate condition we need to show that $f_{T,*}$ preserves quasi-coherent sheaves in Proposition 5.1.14.